# JavaScript: Cookies aren't cleared on logout from user page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using cookies to keep the user's information present on the front end. Logging them in is happening through `Passport`.

On login, the code sets the cookies from the user's information returned from `Passport`.

On logout, the cookies are unset and then `/auth/logout` is called to log the user.

Everything works with login/logout, but whenever I try to delete the cookies on logout, nothing happens.

**This only occurs on the `user.js` page of my site**. I am able to successfully log off from any other page

Here's my code:

**Dynamically Setting the navbar**

```
document.getElementById( 'navigation-bar' ).innerHTML = 
'<ul>'+
  "<li><button onclick='Home();' id='home-link'>Home</button></li>"+
  "<li><a id='recipes-link' href='/recipes'>Recipes</a></li>"+
  "<li><a id='festivals-link' href='/festivals'>Festivals</a></li>"+
  "<li><button id='logout-button' onclick='Logout()'>Logout</button></li>"+
 '</ul>';
```

**Logout Function**

```
function Logout() {

        //Sets each cookie's expire time to 1970, forcing expire.
        DeleteCookies();

        //Runs Passport's 'logout' function
        window.open( '/auth/logout',  '_parent' );

}
```

**Setting The Cookies**

```
function Login () {

    //Setting user parameters.
    let login = { email: null, password: null };

    login.email = document.getElementById( 'email' ).value;
    login.password = document.getElementById( 'password' ).value;

    PostRequest( '/auth/login', login, 'application/json', ( status, data ) => {

        if ( status == 200 ) {
            //Set 'expireTime' to current date and then add 1 hour to it.
            let expireTime = new Date( Date.now() );
            expireTime.setHours( expireTime.getHours() + 1 );

            // Parse the return data.
            let user = JSON.parse(data);

            //Set cookie for each user key. 
            for ( const key in user ) {
                document.cookie = key + '=' + user[key] + ';expires=' + expireTime.toUTCString() + ";";
            }

            //Open user's profile in another window using name as url.
            window.open( '/user/' + user.username, '_parent' );
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }

    });

}
```

**Deleting The Cookies**

```
function DeleteCookies() {
    console.log( 'this is running' );

    //Use old date to expire the cookies
    let expire = 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;'

    //Split each cookie into an array element.
    let cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(";");

    //Split the cookie to have name as the first value.
    //Then use the cookie's name to expire the cookie.
    for ( let cookie = 0; cookie < cookiesArray.length; cookie++ ) {
        let name = cookiesArray[cookie].split( "=" )[0];
        document.cookie = name + "=;" + expire;
    }

}
```

**Checking If Cookie Is Set**

```
function IsLoggedIn() {

    //If user is logged in, display the logout button.
    if (  GetCookie( '_id' ) != '' ) {
        document.getElementById( 'logout-button' ).style.display = 'inline-block';
    }

}
```

**user.js code**

```
var user = {};

function UserReady() {

    GetRequest( '/api/me', undefined, ( status, data ) => {

        if ( status === 200 ) {
            user = JSON.parse( data );
            document.getElementById( 'username' ).innerHTML = "Welcome back, " + user.username;
        }

    });

}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at how you are doing your expire code you are going to end up with `expire=expire=`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you for catching that! Unfortunately, the issue still persists even with that bug out of the way.

Comment: You should handle cookies on server side (As they're made for).

Comment: @Hacketo I'm pretty new to cookies, so correct me if I'm wrong; if I wanted to check if the user is logged in still, I would have to send a request to the server. Wouldn't it be less costly to set client side cookies to be checked?

Comment: Server should set-cookie to the client when `/auth/login` is ok, then client does not have to care about it. When you call the endpoint `/auth/logout` the server clear the cookies of the clients (meaning that the client has no longer any identification from Server side).Then from the client you can check if you have any cookies. The cookies are usually linked to a domain with the `path` attribute(if none set default to current url), that mean all page with that domain will have access to the cookies

Comment: Also, each time the client make a request to your server, the request header include all the cookies available for the url, So I don't know if your really have to use cookie for your application, you may look for server sessions

Comment: I was under the impression that whenever I want to get the user cookie via 'Passport', I have to send a get request to l 'api/me'?

Comment: No, you can access them directly via `document.cookie` because both you app page and all your endpoints share the same domain, so they share the same cookies, document.cookie is not a simple string, it update synchronously with the cookies that it know for the current url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122125/discussion-between-hacketo-and-user5854440).